# how to access array values of a mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

After `print_r`ing the results of a `mysqli_query`, I see some sort of array produced. How do I correctly access the values?  (the `[num_rows] => 2` in particular)

`mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 2 [type] => 0 )`

Comment: Good god! There are millions of examples for this on google! And even better: the php documentation for mysqli comes with excellent, easy and specific examples! Why ask here?

Comment: thanks! sometimes i just don't know how to correctly word what i'm searching for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access those properties of the mysqli_result-object as you access any other public property of class xy.

```
<?php
...
printf("Rows: %d", $result->num_rows);
...
?>
```

See here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

But consider to Google first next time.